# Chef and easy_install_package-- how to add -U option

Tags: chef-infra

In chef I need to do easy_install -U package.

```
easy_install_package "distribute" do
  action :install
end
```

How do I modify the above to use the -U option?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "options" parameter for the easy_install resource.

```
easy_install_package "distribute" do
  options "-U"
  action :install
end
```

"options" is available to any kind of package resource built into Chef, and will pass the specified options to the underlying provider.